# Oracle apex write and modifying on specific image

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have question about display the information into images. I have page called Student Information that displays the information of the student. But the problem is it's shown in table I don't know if is it possible to customize it or not. Here is my current page:

[Current page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7Ad5.jpg)

the page I want it looks like this one :

[require page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qowY9.png)

is it possible to writing or modifying images based on a specific query to make it in the require form ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In apex the layout is determined by templates. You can see all the available templates in Shared Components > Templates.

Every component displayed on the screen will have a template. So a form link yours will use a label template, a region template and a page template.

You can customize the templates to your needs, best way is to start by copying an existing template, give it a name to indicate it is yours and start modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use cards. You can make your own template..

select 
-- data
card_primary_key,    -- primary key 
card_secondary_key,  -- secondary key if needed 
card_title,          -- title 
card_subtitle,       -- subtitle 
card_body,           -- card body text 
card_secondary_body, -- card secondary text, positioned near bottom \

-- ui and other attributes
card_icon,           -- icon class, e.g. fa-cloud 
card_badge,          -- badge, can be a small text 
card_image           -- image url, url or blob columns 
from dual

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/card-regions